# Microsoft GraphServiceClient returns "remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, microsoft-graph-api, webclient

I notice strange (for me) behaviour of the GraphServiceClient to connect to Microsoft's Graph API in my .net framework 4.6.1 MVC webapp.
I use a System.Net.WebClient to get or refresh an access token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0 and that works just fine.

However, consuming Microsoft's Graph API using GraphServiceClient, fails under certain circumstances, returning this exception:

> [AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according
>   to the validation procedure.]
>   System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +300
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +180
>
> [WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not
>   establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.]
>   ... (I trimmed the rest for brevity)

What I tried/checked:

- The certificate (Microsoft's) from graph.microsoft.com/ is valid and trusted on my machine and doesn't seem to contain other (proxy) certificates in the chain.
- Using a callback for ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback that returns true, always works (exception not thrown anymore), but I prefer not to use this hack in my code.
- When debugging the ServerCertificateValidationCallback from the above hack, the sslPolicyErrors parameter always seems to be set to "SslPolicyErrors.none", so when does certificate validation fails anyway?
- <strike>- Using System.Net.WebClient to consume the graph API instead of GraphServiceClient, simply works all the time. What does the GraphServiceClient do more in terms of certificate checking than the System.Net.WebClient?</strike> (EDIT: My bad: the webclient had the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback return true)
- Using Postman to consume the graph API using the same access token simply works.
- <strike>Using the System.Net.WebClient and afterwards (see code below) using the GraphServiceClient to fetch the same data simply works, so I CAN get the GraphServiceClient to work, only it has to be preceded by other code that connects to the API using the System.Net.WebClient (this is actually the weirdest part).</strike> (EDIT: My bad: This was normal since the webclient had the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback return true)
- On our staging environment, the GraphServiceClient works as it should (without hacks or preceding WebClient code), so I guess it's a combiation of something on my dev PC and the usage of GraphServiceClient.
- I do have Cisco AMP active on my PC (but I cannot shut it down). There's no proxy server in our network.

Code:

```
private static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string accessToken) {
    return new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));
}

async public static Task<List<Appointment>> GetAppointments(string accessToken, int eventsAmountToGet) {
    List<QueryOption> queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>(){
        new QueryOption("startDateTime", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")),
        new QueryOption("endDateTime",  DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30).ToString("o"))
    };

    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphClient(accessToken);
    //the following line will fail (remote certificate ...) 
    IUserCalendarViewCollectionPage result = await graphClient.Me.CalendarView.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
    return result.Select(x => new Appointment {
        Subject = x.Subject.ToString(),
        Start = x.Start.ToDateTime(),
        End = x.End.ToDateTime(),
        Organiser = x.Organizer.EmailAddress.Name
    }).Take(eventsAmountToGet).ToList();
}
```

Edit:
When using the "ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback return true" hack, I see this data in Fiddler.
What worries me, is the "time" string in the request, which is seemingly in the past. Where does that string get generated?

Request raw:

> CONNECT graph.microsoft.com:443 HTTP/1.1 Host: graph.microsoft.com
>
> A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted
>   the parameters below.
>
> Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2) Random: 5E 67 B7 58 60 39 A6 18 3B 07 3C F0 88
>   17 E4 85 A7 3C 58 76 85 DE F4 0F EF 4C 76 ED DB 10 52 DE **"Time":
>   2/03/2017 1:29:18** SessionID: 43 4C 00 00 8C 73 51 69 9E 8B FB 24 8B E2
>   6B C2 B5 AA 0B E1 45 20 80 F4 98 BE A2 03 DF 1E D8 B3 Extensions: 
>     server_name graph.microsoft.com     supported_groups    x25519 [0x1d],
>   secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]    ec_point_formats    uncompressed
>   [0x0]     signature_algs  rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384,
>   rsa_pkcs1_sha1, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384,
>   ecdsa_sha1, dsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
>     SessionTicket   empty   extended_master_secret  empty
>     renegotiation_info  00 Ciphers: 
>     [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [009F]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [009E]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>     [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>     [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>     [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>     [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>     [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>     [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>     [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>     [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>     [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>     [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>     [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
>
> Compression:      [00]    NO_COMPRESSION

Response Raw:

> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established FiddlerGateway: Direct StartTime:
>   16:50:48.111 Connection: close
>
> Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS
>   Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in
>   this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.
>
> Secure Protocol: Tls12 Cipher: Aes128 128bits Hash Algorithm: Sha256
>   ?bits Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 255bits
>
> == Server Certificate ========== [Subject]   CN=graph.microsoft.com
>
> [Issuer]   CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 2, OU=Microsoft IT, O=Microsoft
>   Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
>
> [Serial Number]   20000549F729A8A47312D9F3220000000549F7
>
> [Not Before]   27/01/2019 20:09:45
>
> [Not After]   27/01/2021 20:09:45
>
> [Thumbprint]   2D4A597DE7EA5A28474EEAB141E8A085907A900A
>
> [SubjectAltNames] graph.microsoft.com

Comment: Best way of debugging is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the headers in the first good request with the headers in the first bad request.  The request and response are http.  The TLS/SSL validation is performed using TCP.  So you should see both the TCP and HTTP messages.  The TCP could fail and display [FIN] indicating the connection closed.  A good response should contain a status of 200 OK.  A bad status is usually in the 400's or 500's.  Be aware using a token/cookie the validation my be bypassed.  I sometimes delete cookies between attempts so I don't get confused.

Comment: When I use fiddler, nothing really works anymore. Postman returns:
`Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2020-03-06T13:21:26.5905396Z&endDateTime=2020-03-30T13:21:26.5905396Z.`

Graphclient (using proxy to localhost:8888) still returns the same exception.

Fiddler only show the "tunnel to" entries with the TLS info, but without actual data entries

Comment: Do you have fiddler set to return TCP and HTTP messages?  Looks like code wants a proxy on local host at port 8888.  Try from cmd.exe >Netstat -a and see if a server is running at port 8888.  Fix your output message so it not saying you are trying to connect to graph.microsoft.com.  You are actually trying to connect to localhost port 8888.

Comment: I don't know how to configure Fiddler to return TCP messages. The fiddler webservice is definately running, I get lots of entries on netstat -a, and can browse to http://localhost:8888. Not sure what you mean by "Fix your output message". (BTW: thanks for your help already)

Comment: It is under protocols in the filters.  Do not have Fiddler running on the machine I'm using.  I can't find a good webpage that show how to edit the filters.

Comment: I couldn't really find the TCP protocol in the filter. But I added the raw request / response I found in Fiddler to the original post.

Comment: I think the time is the issue data of the certificate.  The response says the is good and certificate is valid between 1/1/19 and 1/1/21.  What bothers me is the 2nd line in the response saying CLOSE, since you are getting a 200 OK it looks like connection completed.  It looks like fiddler tried a number of different encryption methods and was successful.  So did you post a good connection or a bad connection?

Comment: This is a result of a working connection, I get the results I want from the graph API. But the reason why it worked was because the certificate validation was ignored (ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback returns always true), so It's not really a "good" connection.

I tried to use postman as well through Fiddler, but that doesn't work (Could not get any response There was an error connecting to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2020-03-06T13:21:26.5905396Z&endDateTime=2020-03-30T13:21:26.5905396Z.)

Comment: So are you using port 443? What are the differences that are causing the certificate not to be used?  Are you connecting to same server?  I do not believe the certificate is simply being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
The culprit was the dropbox API client, which I also use in the same web application. In particular this line of code:

```
DropboxCertHelper.InitializeCertPinning();
```

This line of code also implements ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback and possibly breaks other code using a HttpClient or WebClient.

More info https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/issues/74